# passwordfield background image

Tags: html, css, image, background

At the moment I am trying to set a background image to a HTML password input field, while this seems to work fine for normal input fields, I get no background image in password fields. Code is as following:
In css:

```
.pw-style{
background: URL(".../test.jpg");
}
```

In HTML:

```
<input class="pw-style" type="password"> ... </input>
```

Here is a example that works for normal input fields:
http://www.atseadesign.com/demos/form_field_with_image.html

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I have tried with password and it works.

Comment: When I change the type to password, it works on your page. Also, you shouldn't do focus and blur with JavaScript. Just use `input:focus` for when the input is focused.

Comment: C Travel: that was a typo, I used "pw-style". Sry for the mistake. gvee: My question is, how can I add a background image to a password field. kmas: What have you tried exactly?

Comment: [working just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/r7nXa/1/) - your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with inline css:

```
<input style="background-image: url('.../test.jpg')" type="password"> ... </input>
```

If this don't resolve your problem and if you want to make something similar with your password input like in your link you cand do something like that:

```
<div class="slidingDiv" style="float:left; background-image: url('.../test.jpg')></div>
<input class="show_hide" style="float:left;" type="password"> ... </input>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

And add Jquery code like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

$('.show_hide').click(function(){  

$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();  

});  

});
```

I hope this is helpfull for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far, the problem was the following:
background: URL(".../test.jpg"); does not work, but background-image: URL(".../test.jpg"); does. Now I have another problem, on pages with simple password fields this works now (e.g. http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms06.htm), but on google mail login and other more complex sites it does not (e.g. https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail). Do you know what causes this issue?

Comment: At the second link I can't see the problem. Please be more explicit about your problem.

Comment: Well at the first link I can see the background-image in the input field, at the second I can't. Should have mentioned that I write a firefox plugin that sets pictures in password fields if the site does not use ssl. And I try to achieve this by using above mentioned code.

Comment: after I inspected with firebug the input from your second link I get this: <input id="Passwd" name="Passwd" type="password" placeholder="Parolă" class=""> . Your input doesn't have a class set

Comment: Yeah of course you can not see that the class is set, because the js that sets the class runs locally on firefox - I write a firefox plugin to change the look of the homepage and want to change the background of the password input field. But that somehow does not work on the google login page.

Comment: You said "Should have mentioned that I write a firefox plugin that sets pictures in password fields if the site does not use ssl" but at second link it looks like that page use ssl. You are sure that your script is running on that page?

Comment: Oh, yeah I am sure, for test purposes I change all password input fields. Also checked that manually, the script adds the class to the input field. Is it possible that some other css or something overwrites the image again?

Comment: you can change in your script background-image: URL(".../test.jpg") !important; instead of background-image: URL(".../test.jpg"); just to be sure, but i don't think that is the problem.